# Atlasboard: how to configure gridster?

Tags: atlasboard

I have an atlasboard-based dashboard. The widgets have already the minimum possible height of "1" in the layout config, but they are still too tall. How or where can I configure gridster to reduce the size of my widgets? I'm looking for the `widget_base_dimensions` of the gridster config object but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You could try defining gridSize in layout or increasing no of rows in gridSize then adjusting height for widget as required.

For eg:

```
"layout": {
    "gridSize" : { "columns" : 25, "rows" : 25 },
    "widgets": [{
      "enabled": true,
      "row": 1,
      "col": 1,
      "width": 5, --no of columns this widget will occupy   
      "height": 5, --no of rows this widget will occupy    
    }
```

Comment: It's the first thing I've tried... `gridSize` doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: What layout config details?

Comment: I could adjust my widget using gridSize config. layout config details in dashboards/*.json file